# No scroll bar for div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a toggle Login/Register template for my page.

However once you click on `Register` its observed that certain elements are not visible.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y11nfdf/).

Here is the entire code.

```
HTML

<div id="container">
<button id="bt1" type="button"> Login
</button>
<button id="bt2" type="button">Register
</button>
<br>
<div id="login">
<table>
<form name="login" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateLogin();">
<tr>
<td>
E-Mail
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pass">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="s_login_submit" value="Login">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
<div id="register">
<form name="register" method="post" action="register_exec.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Salutation
</td>
<td>
<select name="Salutation">
<option value="Ms">Ms</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Dr">Dr</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
First Name
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="F_Name">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Last Name
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="L_Name">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
E-Mail
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password(Min 6 characters)
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pass">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Phone Number(10 digit)
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="P_Number">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
High School Name:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="High_School">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
High School Percentage:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="HS_Percentage">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Intermediate School Name:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Intermediate">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Intermediate Percentage
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="I_Percentage">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Graduation College Name:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Graduation">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Graduation Score:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="G_Score">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Graduation Year:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="G_Year">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
PG College Name:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="PostGraduation">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
PG Score:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="PG_Score">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
PG Year
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="PG_Year">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="Go" value="Go">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
CSS
#login
{

}
#register
{
    display:none;
}
#container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input, select { 
    padding: 9px; 
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5; 
    outline: 0; 
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
    width: 200px; 
    background: #FFFFFF url('bg_form.png') left top repeat-x; 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 25px); 
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px; 
    } 
 table{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
position: relative
padding top:50px
margin-top: 1%;
overflow-y: visible;}

select { 
    width: auto; 
       } 

input:hover, select:hover, 
input:focus, select:focus { 
    border-color: #C9C9C9; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 8px; 
    } 


input[type=submit] { 
    width: auto; 
    padding: 9px 15px; 
    background: #617798; 
    border: 0; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }
    button
    { 
    width: auto; 
    padding: 9px 15px; 
    background: #617798; 
    border: 0; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }
```

Javascript

```
function swap(login, register) {
    document.getElementById(login).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(register).style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    swap('login','register');
});
document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    swap('register','login');
});
function validateForm() {
    var f_name = document.forms["register"]["F_Name"].value;
    if(f_name == null || f_name == "")
    {
    alert("First Name is required");
    return false;
    }

    var l_name = document.forms["register"]["L_Name"].value;
    if(l_name == null || l_name == "")
    {
    alert("Last Name is required");
    return false;
    }

    var email = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    var pass = document.forms["register"]["pass"].value;
    if(pass == null || pass == "")
    {
    alert("Password is required");
    return false;
    }
    else if(pass.length<6)
    {
    alert("password too short");
    return false;
    }

    var P_Number = document.forms["register"]["P_Number"].value;
    if(P_Number == null || P_Number == "")
    {
    alert("Phone Number is required");
    return false;
    }
    P_Number=P_Number.toString().length;
    if(P_Number<10 || P_Number>10)
    {
    alert("Phone Number incorrect")
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @TylerH click register make the result window smaller you see you can't scroll to se the complete form

Comment: @TylerH When you click on register, the form is not visble completely, Notice the Login/Register button

Comment: @CAO I  think its big time ,you should stop using tables in html and  start using using div.

Comment: @Cherry Two reasons, one I am doing web dev after 1.5 years, second I have a crazy deadline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change #container style with this:

```
#container {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
max-height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: What if I want a scroll bar for the entire page and not with respect to the div container?. Put it in a parent div??

Comment: yes, put it in a parent, make parent static height, 100% , 300px or whatever, make parent overflow-y:auto, and make #container height:auto